# How to calculate the inner product of this two complex vectors?

Tags: vectors

How to calculate  the inner product of this two complex vectors?

$\vec x$ = $[4\quad1\; -j\quad4]$ $\:$ and $\:$ $\vec y$ = $[-1\;-2j\quad 2\quad j]$

Is the inner product same as the normal dot product?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not exactly, the so-called ["sesquilinear dot product"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form) is similar to the ordinary dot product but you have to take the conjugated values of the first vector (or the second, according to a different convention).

Answer (score 0):

Let $E=\mathbb C^4$.

Let  $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in E $ and $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)\in E$ and $$\langle.,.\rangle:E\times E\to\mathbb C,(x,y)\mapsto x_1\bar{y_1}+x_2\bar{y_2}+x_3\bar{y_3}+x_4\bar{y_4}$$(you could have define $\langle.,.\rangle$ differently as @Jean Marie told you.)

The best is to see on an example how it works :

Let $x_0=(4,1,-j,4)$ and $y_0=(-1,-2j,2,j)$ with $j=-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i$, I suppose, such that $\bar{j}=j^2$ and $1+j+j^2=0\color{red}{(*)}$.

Then $\langle x_0,y_0\rangle :=4\times(-1)+1\times(-2j^2)+(-j)\times 2+4\times j^2$, according to $\color{red}{(*)}$.

Then $\langle x_0,y_0\rangle=-4-2j^2-2j+4j^2=-4+2j^2-2j=-6-4j=-4-2\sqrt3i $